# How to compare result type to be subclass of abstract class to match to?

Tags: scala, inheritance, matcher, specs2

I have a method with signature

```
def save(u: User): Future[Option[UserServiceError]]
```

that I want to test with Specs2.

I've got the following type hierarchy:

```
abstract class UserServiceError(message: String)
object UserAlreadyExist extends UserServiceError("User already exists")
```

then, test code looks like this:

```
users.save(...) must beSome(users.UserAlreadyExist).await
```

so I expect matcher `beSome` to understand that `UserAlreadyExist` is a subtype of `UserServiceError` from method signature.

However, it gives me an compile time type check error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[core.model.services.UserService#UserAlreadyExist.type]]]
[error]  required: org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[core.model.services.UserService#UserServiceError]]]
```

I have an inkling that I miss something very basic here, like `UserAlreadyExist.type` isn't supposed to conform with `UserServiceError[without .type]`.

Where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't taken into account that you can have matchers inside `beSome()` so with next changes test code works (see **beEqualTo**):

```
must beSome(beEqualTo(UserService.UserAlreadyExist)).await
```

I moved UserServiceError's into UserService's companion object also.